# regression of two vectors by kalman filter example

Tags: r, regression, signal-processing, kalman-filter

Here is an example of how I do a roll linear regression of two vectors

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
res <- rep(NA,length(x))
for(i in 5:length(x)){
  ii <- (i-4):i
   LR <- lm(y[ii]~x[ii])$residuals  
    res[i] <- tail(LR,1)}
```

I would like to see an example of how this can be done with an adaptive kalman filter

I'm interested in [this article](https://palomar.home.ece.ust.hk/MAFS5310_lectures/Rsession_pairs_trading_with_R.html) but the code examples are too incomprehensible for me, I would like to get a simpler and more understandable use case

Comment: Well, the linked article already give you some very simple examples and the code to run them. What is missing there?

Comment: I am not familiar with the math of the kalman filter, I don't understand how it works in this code, I don't understand how it works in a sliding window.. It is constantly retraining with each iteration or the model is trained once.. Therefore, I would like to get a simple example like this working

Comment: So maybe you know better than me :)
Trying to answer your question in the [KFAS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KFAS/KFAS.pdf) documentation you can se that a SSModel has a stationary option, that defaults to TRUE. So I take that even though you have the index `t` in the equations, the process is stationary, in the sense that the filter is modeled as a time invariant linear system.